# What are the benefits of deploying binary dll for website rather than source code?

Tags: asp.net, deployment

I have a small internal app, and I am arguing against myself why I should not just copy the entire source folder to production, as supposed to Publish, which compiles the .cs files to .dll.

But I can't think of any realistic benefits one way or another, other than to reduce the temptation to make direct logic change on production. What do you think?

Comment: Never underestimate the benefits of reducing the temptation for developers to hack!

Answer (score 2):

It eliminates the temptation to just change that one little thing in production...

Also, it secures the code against malicious changes, it adds extra steps between "build" and "deploy" which can be used as a natural QA speed bump, it increases start up time and a billion other things.

Answer (score 1):

Well, for one thing... it makes sure that your site compiles.

Apart from that, check out [Hanselman's Web Deployment Made Awesome: If You're Using XCopy, You're Doing It Wrong](http://channel9.msdn.com/events/MIX/MIX10/FT14)

Answer (score 1):

Two main things:

1. As antisanity points out, it lets you verify that all the pages on your site actually compile, which goes a long way toward catching a number of bugs before they get very far.
2. The website will end up compiling these files the first time they get accessed anyway. By precompiling them, you'll save time on the first load, which will make your application feel a little more responsive to a few of your users.

Answer (score 1):

Well, I can agree with you only if you're talking just about views. If you're talking about controllers, I guess you'd need 'em compiled in order to run :).

Okay, joking aside, I'm for a complete binary deployment mainly for:

- being sure that my code compiles (at least)
- speed up view generation (or first time compile)
- simplify management of patches (I deliver just a dll and not the entire webapp)

regards

M.

Answer (score 1):

There are a number of reasons why you should publish your application:

1. It will perform better;
2. You know that the code compiles;
3. It's cleaner (no `.cs` files cluttering the folder);
4. Some security benefits by not exposing the source code;
5. You can package your application for deployment to testing, staging, and production